# If AB = BA, what are the eigenvalues of A + B and AB?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $A$ and $B$ be $n$-square matrices. If $AB = BA$, what are the
>   eigenvalues of $A + B$ and $AB$ in terms of those of $A$ and $B$?

I show that an eigenvector of A is also an eigenvector of B. I am both having trouble doing this and failing to see how I would complete the proof after. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If $AB=BA$ then any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $AB$ is a product $\lambda=\alpha\beta$ of eigenvalues $\alpha$ of $A$, $\beta$ of $B$, where $\alpha,\beta,\lambda$ correspond to a common eigenvector of the above matrices. This has been shown on MSE here. For the relation of eigenvalues for $A+B$ I do not know a general result. We could take $B=-A$, for example.